# Cannot deploy correctly NestJS on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, nestjs

I'm trying to deploy my Nest.js on Google App Engine but it cannot be deployed successfully...

Reproduce:

```sh
nest new my-project
```

In `src/main.ts`

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
}
bootstrap();
```

In `package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "nest-gcloud-test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "private": true,
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "main": "dist/main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
        "build": "nest build",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
        "start": "npm run start:dev",
        "start:dev": "node dist/main --watch",
        "start:debug": "node dist/main --debug --watch",
        "start:prod": "node dist/main",
        "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
        "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
        "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.13",
        "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.13",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.13",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nestjs/cli": "^7.5.6",
        "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.2.7",
        "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.13",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
        "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.2",
        "eslint": "^7.20.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "supertest": "^6.1.3",
        "ts-jest": "^26.5.2",
        "ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
        "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
        "typescript": "^4.1.5"
    },
    "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "json",
            "ts"
        ],
        "rootDir": "src",
        "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "**/*.(t|j)s"
        ],
        "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
        "testEnvironment": "node"
    }
}
```

In `app.yaml`

```yaml
runtime: nodejs12
```

and deploy

```
gcloud app deploy
```

After a while the GAE log shows that the Nest application successfully started but GAE shutdowns immediately with the message:

```
[start] 2021/03/24 20:31:36.643972 No entrypoint specified, using default entrypoint: /serve
[start] 2021/03/24 20:31:36.647170 Starting app
[start] 2021/03/24 20:31:36.647513 Executing: /bin/sh -c exec /serve
[start] 2021/03/24 20:31:36.658103 Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"app/invalid" Address:127.0.0.1:8080
[start] 2021/03/24 20:31:36.660574 Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"app/valid" Address:127.0.0.1:8081
[serve] 2021/03/24 20:31:36.682824 Serve started.
[serve] 2021/03/24 20:31:36.683836 Args: {runtimeLanguage:nodejs runtimeName:nodejs12 memoryMB:256 positional:[]}
[serve] 2021/03/24 20:31:36.686634 Running /bin/sh -c exec npm run start:dev

> nest-gcloud-test@0.0.1 start:dev /workspace
> node dist/main --watch

[32m[Nest] 31 - [39m03/24/2021, 8:31:39 PM [38;5;3m[NestFactory] [39m[32mStarting Nest application...[39m
[32m[Nest] 31 - [39m03/24/2021, 8:31:39 PM [38;5;3m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mAppModule dependencies initialized[39m[38;5;3m +45ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 31 - [39m03/24/2021, 8:31:39 PM [38;5;3m[RoutesResolver] [39m[32mAppController {}:[39m[38;5;3m +6ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 31 - [39m03/24/2021, 8:31:39 PM [38;5;3m[RouterExplorer] [39m[32mMapped {, GET} route[39m[38;5;3m +3ms[39m
[32m[Nest] 31 - [39m03/24/2021, 8:31:39 PM [38;5;3m[NestApplication] [39m[32mNest application successfully started[39m[38;5;3m +2ms[39m
[start] 2021/03/24 20:32:53.970253 Quitting on terminated signal
[start] 2021/03/24 20:32:53.970940 Start program failed: failed to detect app after start: ForAppStart(): [aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/invalid" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:120069 aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/valid" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:120115]
```

No error logs on `stderr`.

---

However I can successfully deploy a simple http server as follows:

`app.js`

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end(`Hello World\n`);
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
    console.log('app started');
});
```

`app.yaml`

```yaml
runtime: nodejs12
```

`package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "appengine",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Run `gcloud app deploy` successfully and no problems.

---

Any helps appreciated.

## Solution

Add `"gcp-build": "npm run build"` to `package.json`

Then it's now working fine without any problems.

Comment: you should answer your own question! that's allowed on stackoverflow. just move your 'edit' for the solution down to the answer section and then you can even mark your own answer as the correct solution. this will help other people quickly locate the answer when browsing SO since right now your answer is combined with your question

Answer (score 3):

Solution
Add "gcp-build": "npm run build" to package.json

Then it's now working fine without any problems.